# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).froalaEditor is not a function// solution is found but not sure how to use it

Tags: javascript, jquery, froala

I just simply want to use `froala` text editor on my site, but I get Uncaught TypeError: $(...).froalaEditor is not a function.

I googled it and found the solution [here](https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor/issues/931)  but I don't know how to use this source. Mainly because I don't have this anywhere in my code

```
var $ = require('jquery');
require('node_modules/froala-editor/js/froala_editor.min.js');

$(function() {
  var $target = $('<div>').appendTo('body');
  $target.froalaEditor()
});
```

I simply followed the documentation, https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor. I used {{form.media}} at the top to use it but on console I get the above mentioned error. Can someone please tell me how to use the solution in github?

Comment: What's the problem? The GitHub you linked to has the solution - just change your `require` code to match the one found in the reply on that thread.

Comment: yes but thing is I don't have that jquery in my html file. In documentation it simply says I have to put {{form.media}}

Comment: @MatthewHerbst this is the docu https://github.com/pydanny/django-wysiwyg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

require('node_modules/froala-editor/js/froala_editor.min.js')**($)**;

You see at the end?

Comment: Yes I saw that, but I don't know where to put that jquery function, in the documentation https://github.com/pydanny/django-wysiwyg I only needed to put {{form.media}}

Comment: no I mean I don't know where to put the whole thing, in documentation it says I only need to put {{form.media}} then I got the error. So I googed and I got the github page with the  solution. but the problem with that solution is I don't have any code like var $ = require('jquery'); (the one I posted)

Comment: you should have posted your code then, and ask where to put it in. usually these thing go to the very first lines of your file

Comment: hmm I thought I put that above.., above html file?

Comment: Please don't guess, just include your code in the question, so that people with more experience can see it and help you

Comment: here I just made the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34941170/using-django-froala-editor-the-editor-works-in-admin-page-wont-work-in-post-pa