# froala django doesn't work in template

Tags: python, django, wysiwyg, froala

i'm trying to use froala WYSIWYG in my django project i installed and prepared everything as it is mention in the docs 
but the content field still displayed as text field
so any solution ??

my code
forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import BlogPost
from froala_editor.widgets import FroalaEditor

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=FroalaEditor())
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ('title','body','thumb','tags')
```

template

```
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
        <html>
        <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link href="{{STATIC_URL}}froala_editor/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="{{STATIC_URL}}froala_editor/css/froala_editor.min.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{STATIC_URL}}froala_editor/js/froala_editor.min.js"></script
    </head>
    <body>
<form method="POST" class="padding" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ editor|crispy }}        
  </form>
    </body>

        </html>
```

note that

```
 editor = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES )
```

in my views

and i'm having trouble with jquery cookies 
error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getCookie is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):72)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: thanks to @Awin this is the answer :
[Using django-froala-editor, the editor works in admin page won't work in post page?Uncaught TypeError: $(…).froalaEditor is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34941170/using-django-froala-editor-the-editor-works-in-admin-page-wont-work-in-post-pa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this answer [Using django-froala-editor, the editor works in admin page won't work in post page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34941170/using-django-froala-editor-the-editor-works-in-admin-page-wont-work-in-post-pa) the problem was in Jquery I replaced the main Jquery file before Froala scripts

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked in the browser to see whether the files are loading? You're referencing static files both by `/static/...` and `{{ STATIC_URL }}...`, but I'd recommend using the [`{% static '...' %}` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-static) you've imported. It looks like this:

```
<link href="{% static 'froala_editor/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
```

For that to work, you'll need to set up the Django staticfiles app in your project's settings if you haven't already. [The Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) will help you get that part sorted out.

Comment: there files like ' froala_editor/css/froala-django.css' and  'froala_editor/js/froala-django.js' are not found even in the directory and my staticfiles path is installed correctly

Comment: those files are referenced in froala_editor/widgets.py

Comment: @a7me3D For people searching later, could you mention what fixed it? Also, if my answer helped, feel free to accept it!

Comment: i found this answer[Using django-froala-editor, the editor works in admin page won't work in post page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34941170/using-django-froala-editor-the-editor-works-in-admin-page-wont-work-in-post-pa) the probleme was in jquery i replaced the main jquery file before froala scripts